# shiny R - allow scrollbars to be over div not within div

Tags: css, r, shiny

I've got a list of options, for multiple inputs, and I want each `selectInput` to show the full length of options. However, they are only showing within the `splitLayout` divs. How can I tell a `select` form element to show the dropdowns on top of everything else.

[image: Picture of the Problem]

Below is my source code:

```
library(shiny)

app <- shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(fluidRow(h1('yo')),
                 fluidRow(
                   column(
                     4,
                     splitLayout(
                       cellWidths = c('50%', '25%', '25%'),
                       textInput('happy', label = 'mood'),
                       selectInput('letter', 'which', LETTERS),
                       selectInput('letter', 'what', letters)
                     ),
                     splitLayout(
                       cellWidths = c('50%', '25%', '25%'),
                       textInput('happy', label = 'mood'),
                       selectInput('letter', 'which', LETTERS),
                       selectInput('letter', 'what', letters)
                     ),
                     splitLayout(
                       cellWidths = c('50%', '25%', '25%'),
                       textInput('happy', label = 'mood'),
                       selectInput('letter', 'which', LETTERS),
                       selectInput('letter', 'what', letters)
                     )

                   ),
                   column(
                     4,
                     splitLayout(
                       cellWidths = c('50%', '25%', '25%'),
                       textInput('happy', label = 'mood'),
                       selectInput('letter', 'which', LETTERS),
                       selectInput('letter', 'what', letters)
                     ),
                     splitLayout(
                       cellWidths = c('50%', '25%', '25%'),
                       textInput('happy', label = 'mood'),
                       selectInput('letter', 'which', LETTERS),
                       selectInput('letter', 'what', letters)
                     ),
                     splitLayout(
                       cellWidths = c('50%', '25%', '25%'),
                       textInput('happy', label = 'mood'),
                       selectInput('letter', 'which', LETTERS),
                       selectInput('letter', 'what', letters)
                     )
                   ),
                   column(
                     4,
                     splitLayout(
                       cellWidths = c('50%', '25%', '25%'),
                       textInput('happy', label = 'mood'),
                       selectInput('letter', 'which', LETTERS),
                       selectInput('letter', 'what', letters)
                     ),
                     splitLayout(
                       cellWidths = c('50%', '25%', '25%'),
                       textInput('happy', label = 'mood'),
                       selectInput('letter', 'which', LETTERS),
                       selectInput('letter', 'what', letters)
                     ),
                     splitLayout(
                       cellWidths = c('50%', '25%', '25%'),
                       textInput('happy', label = 'mood'),
                       selectInput('letter', 'which', LETTERS),
                       selectInput('letter', 'what', letters)
                     )
                   )

                 )),

  server = function(input, output) {
  }
)

runApp(app)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a different approach to control widget alignment using `div`. This will not overlap the `choices` from your `selectInput` box.

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(fluidRow(h1('yo')),
                 fluidRow(
                   column(4,
                          div(style = "display:inline-block; width: 35%;",
                              textInput('happy', label = 'mood')),
                          div(style = "display:inline-block; width: 25%;",
                              selectInput('letter', 'which', LETTERS)),
                          div(style = "display:inline-block; width: 25%;",
                              selectInput('letter', 'what', letters))
                          ),

                   column(4,
                          div(style = "display:inline-block; width: 35%;",
                              textInput('happy', label = 'mood')),
                          div(style = "display:inline-block; width: 25%;",
                              selectInput('letter', 'which', LETTERS)),
                          div(style = "display:inline-block; width: 25%;",
                              selectInput('letter', 'what', letters))
                          ),

                   column(4,
                          div(style = "display:inline-block; width: 35%;",
                              textInput('happy', label = 'mood')),
                          div(style = "display:inline-block; width: 25%;",
                              selectInput('letter', 'which', LETTERS)),
                          div(style = "display:inline-block; width: 25%;",
                              selectInput('letter', 'what', letters))
                          )
                   ),

                 fluidRow(
                   column(4,
                          div(style = "display:inline-block; width: 35%;",
                              textInput('happy', label = 'mood')),
                          div(style = "display:inline-block; width: 25%;",
                              selectInput('letter', 'which', LETTERS)),
                          div(style = "display:inline-block; width: 25%;",
                              selectInput('letter', 'what', letters))
                   ),

                   column(4,
                          div(style = "display:inline-block; width: 35%;",
                              textInput('happy', label = 'mood')),
                          div(style = "display:inline-block; width: 25%;",
                              selectInput('letter', 'which', LETTERS)),
                          div(style = "display:inline-block; width: 25%;",
                              selectInput('letter', 'what', letters))
                   ),

                   column(4,
                          div(style = "display:inline-block; width: 35%;",
                              textInput('happy', label = 'mood')),
                          div(style = "display:inline-block; width: 25%;",
                              selectInput('letter', 'which', LETTERS)),
                          div(style = "display:inline-block; width: 25%;",
                              selectInput('letter', 'what', letters))
                          )
                   )

                 ),

  server = function(input, output) {
  }
)
```

EDIT: Alternate solution without `div` or any styling options.

Another simpler way to align the widgets is using `column` for each boxes as shown below.

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(fluidRow(h1('yo')),
                 fluidRow(
                   column(2,
                          textInput('happy', label = 'mood')),
                   column(1,
                          selectInput('letter', 'which', LETTERS)),
                   column(1,
                          selectInput('letter', 'what', letters)),
                   column(2,
                          textInput('happy', label = 'mood')),
                   column(1,
                          selectInput('letter', 'which', LETTERS)),
                   column(1,
                          selectInput('letter', 'what', letters)),
                   column(2,
                          textInput('happy', label = 'mood')),
                   column(1,
                          selectInput('letter', 'which', LETTERS)),
                   column(1,
                          selectInput('letter', 'what', letters))
                   ),

                 fluidRow(
                   column(2,
                          textInput('happy', label = 'mood')),
                   column(1,
                          selectInput('letter', 'which', LETTERS)),
                   column(1,
                          selectInput('letter', 'what', letters)),
                   column(2,
                          textInput('happy', label = 'mood')),
                   column(1,
                          selectInput('letter', 'which', LETTERS)),
                   column(1,
                          selectInput('letter', 'what', letters)),
                   column(2,
                          textInput('happy', label = 'mood')),
                   column(1,
                          selectInput('letter', 'which', LETTERS)),
                   column(1,
                          selectInput('letter', 'what', letters))
                 )

                 ),

  server = function(input, output) {
  }
)
```

Comment: This works even better than I had expected, allowing me to use my custom CSS file to further style these divs. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome... glad I could help !!